# Setting titleTextAttriubutes of navigationBar crashes the app only on ios 7.1 device not simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

Here is the code that crashes the app

```
navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NAV_BAR_TINT_COLOR]
```

This is the output

```
2014-08-13 18:21:47.567 demoapp[1214:60b] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x102e90000 of class '_TtCSs29_NativeDictionaryStorageOwner0000000156D27548' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
(lldb)
```

This line used to work with xcode 6 beta 4, I just updated to xcode 6 beta 5 and app crashes

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Comment: can i know y m got minus? please atleast try

Comment: This is Objective-C and the OP is about Swift.

Answer (score 0):

```
  This code work for me.May be it's helpful for you.

 let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor()]
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =  titleDict
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```